# How to get the option to set behave as BDD framework in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm, python-behave

I try to get BDD running in PyCharm 2016.2.3 with Gherkin and behave as shown in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nmBbR97Vsv8, but when I get to the part where I need to enter the BDD framework behave [image] I am not able to get anything like that: [image] How do I get this option?

Btw. I did install the Gherkin plugin.

Answer (score 3):

- First search for behave in settings and enable "Python BDD support for engines, based on Gherkin(cucumber, lettuce, behave)"[image]

  - Then select the BDD framework you want to work with as below
    [image]

Answer (score 1):

The real reason can be: you are using a community version of PyCharm and BDD feature is not included, see [Feature Spotlight: Behavior-Driven Development in PyCharm](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2014/09/feature-spotlight-behavior-driven-development-in-pycharm/)

> Note: The BDD support is available only in the PyCharm Professional Edition, not in the Community Edition.

Answer (score 0):

For community edition you can try this:

1.Open your project.

2.Click on setting icon.

3.Under your project name click on python interpreter.

4.Click on + icon

5.Then Search for Behave and install it and then add gherkin plug in
[image]